# I'm trying to create a remix project but npx create-remix@latest doesn't work for me

Tags: node.js

I have this problem when I run the `npx create-remix@latest` command, I don't understand this problem because I only run the command to create a remix project

[Bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF9lv.png)